# Swift: Activity Indicator with Async Web tasks

Tags: ios, swift, api, asynchronous, uiactivityindicatorview

Evening I have the following problem:

## The Problem

My app is a **web based app**. It downloads the data from an **API** and you can display the results through different `tableViews`.

When the **LandingPage** is loaded the app starts to download the data. The data are download through many async tasks.

I would like that the user **can't** use the app until the data are all downloaded, showing an `activity indicator`.

I was thinking to show the activity indicator as soon the page is loaded and than stop it when the async **closure** is called.

The problem is that are like 5 async functions, and every async task make others async task.

So is there a way to understand if there is an async task running, and if yes: **show the indicator**, if not: **stop the indicator**?

Or, there is a better design patterns to accomplish this?

Comment: Look into using `DispatchGroup`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100847/checking-for-multiple-asynchronous-responses-from-alamofire-and-swift and other similar questions. The use of Alamofire is irrelevant. Use what you need for the actual async tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

as @rmaddy has suggested I used the `GroupDispatch`

First of all I've create a **GroupDispatch object**.

For every async call, I've passed the `groupDispatch` object as `parameter`, and inside the function i've used `group.enter()`, so every time the function is called it enters inside the group.
While in the closure I've used the `group.leave()` method.

At the end I've used `group.notify` to be notified when all the async calls are done.

It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of async, you should use promise kit:

[Promise Kit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)

With this, you can manage all your requests and even perform different error handling for each one and show or hide loading indicators whenever you want.

Comment: thank you for you answer. But I would like to not use external Library

Comment: So you can implement "votes" where each task has one vote and when all have voted you can hide your HUD.